# Laravel multiple tables data filter

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am using Laravel 5 and I have 3 database tables `projects`, `applications`, `users` and their table structure are as followed:

**Projects**

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->char('status',1);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Applications**

```
Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->char('status');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Users**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now, I wanted to perform a query to return all the projects where a specific user has not submitted any application to that project yet. So far this is the closest result I could get but it will return `NULL` in the `projects.id` for every projects that have no applications.

```
DB::table('projects')
        ->leftjoin('applications', 'applications.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->where('applications.user_id', '!=', $user->id)
        ->orWhereNull('applications.id')
        ->get();
```

**Query Result**

```
{
    "total":1,
    "per_page":5,
    "current_page":1,
    "last_page":1,
    "next_page_url":null,
    "prev_page_url":null,
    "from":1,"to":1,
    "data":[{
        "id":null,
        "name":"Project2",
        "description":"Project2 detail",
        "status":null,
        "created_at":null,
        "updated_at":null,
        "project_id":null,
        "user_id":null
    }]
}
```

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out how to do this by using two different query and combined them together.

**1) Select all user applications' project_id**

```
$user_applications = Application::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->select('project_id as id')
        ->get();
```

**2) Select the projects where the projects are not from previous list**

```
$projects_not_applied = DB::table('projects')
        ->whereNotIn('id',$user_applications)
        ->get();
```

Query result (user has not apply for project 2):

```
[{
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Project2",
    "description":"Project2 detail",
    "status":"n",
    "created_at":"2016-03-14 15:09:58",
    "updated_at":"2016-03-14 15:09:58"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('projects')
    ->leftjoin('applications', function($join){
        $join->on('applications.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
            ->where('applications.user_id', '=', $user->id); 
    })
    ->whereNull('applications.id')
    ->get();
```

Think that's what your looking for

Comment: this query still give me the same result with `project.id` = `NULL` :(

Comment: how are you trying to retrieve that value

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? I don't quite get your question